# How to sort the contents of a list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have the following list:

```
filenames=["SecretOfChimneys_1925.txt",
        "DeathInTheClouds_1935.txt",
        "SparklingCyanide_1945.txt",
        "HickoryDickoryDock_1955.txt",
        "AtBertramsHotel_1965.txt",
        "Curtain_1975.txt"]
books=[]
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as fin:
        text=fin.read()
        books.append(text)
```

I need to make a list of book titles ordered by year, with the underscore character and the year removed. For example, the first book title should be "SecretOfChimneys". Call your list booktitles.

Is there a way to use the fact that titles are already sorted by year in books and just select the tiles from that?

Or should I use a sorting algorithm with filename?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `filenames.sort()` sorts the list in place and returns `None`, it doesn't return it. Use `sorted()` to return a new list.

Comment: If the books are guaranteed to be already sorted by year, there is indeed no need to sort. Just trim the strings to remove the last underscore and what follows. [I say last in case the titles can themselves contain an underscore.]

Comment: Since books are already in the desired order in filenames, you just need to traverse the list using its current order and strip out the titles: `titles = [f.split("_")[0] for f in filenames]`.

Comment: Why did you change the question to say that the list is already sorted. I answered the question that asked how to sort it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a lambda as the key when sorting. Then use a list comprehension to extract just the title from the sorted list.

```
booktitles = [f.split('_')[0] for f in 
    sorted(filenames, key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]))
]
```

Comment: Why do you sort again ?

Comment: I only sort once.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, that's really helpful. So to get bookyears, following your example I am using this code: `bookyears= [f.split('_')[1] for f in sorted(filenames, key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]))]` but I am getting years with ".txt" at the end. How could get rid of the .txt?

Comment: You sort a sorted list.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The question didn't originally say that the list was sorted, that was added in an edit.

Comment: @EffectiveLearning  `split('.')[0]` is for removing the `.txt` extension.

Comment: Strangely, this edit wasn't made by the OP. That changes the question significantly !

Comment: Yes it was. It was version #3 by the OP. There was a minor edit by someone else in between.